# Pandas DataFrame add transformed rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to expand my dataset.

I have a `DataFrame`, and for some fields, I know how to transform their row to a new row with different field values.

For example, for my case, I know that for every `male` who is a `programmer`, you can create the same line for `female`, `data scientist`. Because their other features will remain the same.

**Source.csv**:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| sex  |    work    | salary | days |
|------|------------|--------|------|
| male | programmer |  1000  |  5   |
| male |     QA     |  1200  |  5   |
| male | programmer |  1500  |  4   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Output should be**:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|  sex   |      work      | salary | days |
|--------|----------------|--------|------|
|  male  |   programmer   |  1000  |  5   |
|  male  |       QA       |  1200  |  5   |
|  male  |   programmer   |  1500  |  4   |
| female | data scientist |  1000  |  5   |
| female | data scientist |  1500  |  4   |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

What is the way to duplicate all rows that contain `male`, `programmer`, so that the added rows will have the values `female`, `data scientist`?

Comment: [please provide an example to replicate the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @anky_91 I hope the examples I have added are sufficient. I did not know what code to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a nested dict to replace on slicing of `male` , `programmer` and `append` to `df`

```
dct = {'sex': {'male': 'female'}, 'work': {'programmer': 'data scientist'}}
df.append(df[df.sex.eq('male')&df.work.eq('programmer')].replace(dct), ignore_index=True)


Out[481]:
      sex            work  salary  days
0    male      programmer    1000     5
1    male              QA    1200     5
2    male      programmer    1500     4
3  female  data scientist    1000     5
4  female  data scientist    1500     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter by boolean mask  by comparing using [`series.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and create a [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html), then change the values and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
m = df[df.sex.eq('male') & df.work.eq('programmer')].copy()
m.loc[:, ['sex', 'work']] = ['female', 'data scientist']
pd.concat([df, m], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
      sex            work salary days
0    male      programmer   1000    5
1    male              QA   1200    5
2    male      programmer   1500    4
3  female  data scientist   1000    5
4  female  data scientist   1500    4
```